# SOQL Query not returning results for Oldvalue/Newvalue in workbench

Tags: query, workbench

I have a query as below:

```
 SELECT  CaseId,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Field,Id,IsDeleted,NewValue,OldValue FROM CaseHistory
```

In my query `NewValue`,`OldValue` not getting in workbench.But same query working in developer console.May I know the reason why not getting in workbench.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of what it is returning ?

Comment: @ karthikselva thanks for your response.I am not able to add screenshot here.

Comment: I know that oldvalue and newvalue are special. For example, in reports you can query these fields, but you can't filter on them. Maybe your issue is related.

Comment: What is the type of the field for which you want to see the changes?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the same login in both cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried your query in workbench and I was surprised not to see any result for `Newvalue` and `Oldvalue`.

Then i shuffled the positions of NewValue and OldValue in the query and saw that it works.

> Query:
>   `SELECT NewValue,OldValue, CaseId,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Field,Id,IsDeleted FROM CaseHistory`

Result:

[image]

I believe it might be a bug.

Comment: That is an interesting find, I like these kinds of errors.

Comment: When I try SELECT OldValue,NewValue,Id,Field FROM CaseHistory WHERE Field = 'Status' ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC NULLS FIRST, I get as columns: Id Unknown_Field__1 Unknown_Field__2 Field, and I still don't know which is the oldvalue and which the newvalue. And column aliasing is not allowed for simple columns,

Comment: Also, the number of returned columns depends on whether I use a WHERE clause or not, in my case at least.

Comment: @Sander de Jong..  I think there is some bug in Workbench. i am getting proper results in Developer Console for your Query.